# How do I remove backticks in formatted mysql query?

Tags: mysql, node.js, npm, xlsx

Okay so I've extracted some values in excel using the npm package 'xlsx' and I want to run a MySql query with the formatted result.

**Excel extraction**

```
    let wb= xlsx.readFile(filePath);         //GET WORKBOOK
    let ws= wb.Sheets[wb.SheetNames[0]];     //SELECT THE FIRST SHEET IN THE ARRAY
    let data= xlsx.utils.sheet_to_json(ws);  //CONVERT DATA TO JSON OBJECT
    let s ='';                               //CREATE VARIABLE TO HOLD FORMATTED STRING
    for(let i=0; i<data.length; i++){
        s+= "'" + data[i].id +"',";       //FORMAT OBJECT TO STRING
    }
    let fullString= s.substr(0, s.length-1); //STORE FORMATED STRING IN VARIABLE REMOVING FINAL COMMA (,)
```

**Formated string is like so:**

```
'2019-0027178','2019-0027179','2019-0027180','2019-0027181','2019-0027182','2019-0027183'
```

**MySql query is like so:**

```
SELECT name, email, phone FROM persons WHERE id IN (?),
[fullString]
```

**What's expected:**

A json object containing the requested information like so:

```
[{name: "John", email: "john.doe@email.com", phone: "123456789"}, ... ]
```

**Actual result:**

An empty array like so:

```
[]
```

**Investigation and Thoughts**

I found out backticks were being added to the query string like so:

```
... WHERE id IN (`'2019-0027178','2019-0027179','2019-0027180','2019-0027181','2019-0027182','2019-0027183'`)
```

**Actual actual main question:**

Is there something I'm doing wrong or is there a proper way to do this?

**EDIT!**

So for a single question mark ie. `... WHERE id in (?)`, I get the empty object as stated above. But for two question marks ie. `... WHERE id IN (??)`, I get this error:

```
{
    "code": "ER_BAD_FIELD_ERROR",
    "errno": 1054,
    "sqlMessage": "Unknown column ''2019-0027178','2019-0027179','2019-0027180','2019-0027181','2019-0027182','2019-0027183' in 'where clause'",
    "sqlState": "42S22",
    "index": 0,
    "sql": "SELECT name, email, phone FROM persons WHERE id IN (`'2019-0027178','2019-0027179','2019-0027180','2019-0027181','2019-0027182','2019-0027183'`)"
}
```

Comment: it is exscaping the parameter to prevent sql injection, you have to do this with dynamic sql -- parameterized won't work.  or add the elements to a table and do a join

Comment: _"... or add the elements to a table and do a join"_


Please explain that part.

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you had a table called personfilter with the columns key and personid.
You then generate a unique key.  For example 27.  Then the following would do what you want:

```
INSERT INTO personfilter(key,personid)
  values
     (27, '2019-0027178'),
     (27, '2019-0027179'),
     (27, '2019-0027180'),
     (27, '2019-0027181'),
     (27, '2019-0027182'),
     (27, '2019-0027183')
```

Then you could do the following select

```
SELECT name, email, phone 
FROM persons
JOIN personfilter on personfilter.key = 27 and personfilter.personid = persons.id
```

Comment: No wait... This would mean that I have to know exactly what is in the excel file before inserting into the _'personfilter'_ table...  Otherwise how else am I to insert multiple values into the table using Node

Comment: Yes you would.  You get a unique number (current timestamp maybe?) add them in with that key and then call your request.  Oh look you also have a history now of all filters.  Nice side effect.

Answer (score 0):

Okay so I figured I could just 'prepare' the query before executing it.

**~SOLUTION~**

Instead of doing this `let fullString= s.substr(0, s.length-1);` before passing `fullString` as a parameter to the query string, I just did this:

```
let fullString= `SELECT name, email, phone FROM persons WHERE id IN (${s.substr(0, s.length-1)})`;
```

Then passed `fullString` in place of where the actual query was.

**Thanks.**